# Issues reactively updating svelte page on mongodb change stream event handle trigger

Tags: typescript, mongodb, svelte

So what I want to do is rather simple. I have a mongodb collection connected with a svelte page. When document/entry in this collection is updated *externally* so not via the page, I want the page to update its contents to reflect the changes made to the collection. So currently I setup a basic change stream event handler

```js
client
    .db("main_db")
    .collection("QandA_collection")
    .watch([], { fullDocument: "updateLookup" })
    .on("change", (change) => {
        console.log("Change detected in QandA_collection");
        console.log(change);

        const most_recent_data = questions.find(
            {},
            {
                limit: 100,
                projection: {
                    _id: 0,
                },
            }
        ).toArray()
    });
```

But I am a bit unsure how to proceed, I tried using svelte stores but then svelte got angry because I was doing certain disallowed imports. I also tried just calling the `load()` function from the `+page.server.ts` file when the event handler triggered, since I assumed that the load function would trigger an update to the data but this just doesn't seem to have any effect. For reference here is my code for the `+page.svelte` file in the same folder.

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import type { PageData } from "./$types";
    import { enhance } from "$app/forms";
    import { page } from "$app/stores";

    let curr_guild_id: string;
</script>

<h1>FaQ page</h1>

<input bind:value={curr_guild_id} />
<ul>
    {#each $page.data.questions as question}
        {#if question.guild_id == curr_guild_id}
            <li>
                <h3>
                    {question.question}
                </h3>
                <form method="POST" action="?/add_answer" use:enhance>
                    <label>
                        Answer:
                        <input name="answer" />
                        <input
                            type="hidden"
                            name="question"
                            value={question.question}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </li>
        {/if}
    {/each}
</ul>
```

And here is the code for the `load()` function that should be updating the page

```js
export async function load() {
    console.log("Loading questions...");

    const data = await questions
        .find(
            {},
            {
                limit: 100,
                projection: {
                    _id: 0,
                },
            }
        )
        .toArray();

    return {
        questions: data,
    };
}
```

From what I understood the load function is only triggered once when the page is reloaded so my assumption was that re-triggering it would have the same effect but this is evidently not the case. I've thought about some other approaches like just periodically fetching updates but I felt like actually watching for real-time updates and then getting the new data without a page reload is the cleanest solution. Any help here would be greatly appreciated. I'm still very new to all this so just a bit confused on how to properly approach this problem.

### solution update

In the unlikely case anyone ever finds this, the way to get this to work is to use websockets and the node adapter. Some resources for anyone interested

- [*First class support for websockets in sveltekit*](https://github.com/suhaildawood/SvelteKit-integrated-WebSocket)
- [*Discussion about websockets and sveltekit*](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1491)
- [*Web sockets with svelte tutorial*](https://joyofcode.xyz/using-websockets-with-sveltekit)

Comment: If you're looking to get something up quickly, easiest solution is going to be to call invalidateAll on a timer https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/invalidate-all. If you're looking for something more powerful - eg. see updates in real time, you would need to use websockets or HTTP2 events to push data from the server to the browser  https://syncedstore.org/docs/sync-providers